# Is it possible to use sfConfig vars in the routing.yml?

Tags: php, routes, symfony1, config

As it seems it's not possible to insert PHP code as in `settings.yml`, but maybe there is a way to at least access `sfConfig` vars somehow?

Further to Maerlyn's answer, I tried this:

```
sfConfig::set('orgID', 23435);

test:
  url:   /test/:orgID
  param: { module: default, action: index, orgID: %APP_orgID% }
```

I expected that `url_for('@test)` will generate an URI like that `/test/23435` but I only get `/test`. This doesn't appear to work, any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Symfony have you been using? I had no problems using php inside the routing.yml file:

```
test:
  url:   /test/:orgID
  param: { module: default, action: index, orgID: <?php echo sfConfig::get('app_orgID'); ?> }
```

One thing you have to remember, if you use PHP at the end of the line you have to explicitly pass a line end character:

```
requirements:
  id: <?php echo 'something something'."\n"; ?>
```

I was using a parameter defined in `settings.yml` using the `sfConfig::get('sf_<param_name>')`

Answer (score 0):

You can access symfony's values like `%SF_DATA_DIR%`, try it like `%APP_YOUR_VALUE%`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dinamic routing:

```
$routing->prependRoute('test', new sfRoute('/test/:orgID', array(
                    'module' => 'default',
                    'action' => 'index',
                    'orgID' => null
                        )));
```